# Symfony Voters on collection of objects

Tags: symfony, security

I am using Voters to manage permissions on my application and everything works fine for single objects.

What I don't seem to be able to do is apply a Voter on a collection of objects. For example, I have an end-point /persons that will return the complete list of people, but it should be filtered according to the rights of each user (a department manager should only see the people in their own department). Is there any way of doing this with Voters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this can be done using an authorization checker:

```
// your controller

private $authorizationChecker;

public function __construct(AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorizationChecker)
{
    $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
}

// in your action

return array_filter($userCollection, function (User $user) {
    return $this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('VOTER_NAME', $user);
});
```

or simply if you're controllers extend the Symfony's `Controller` class:

```
return array_filter($userCollection, function (User $user) {
    return $this->isGranted('VOTER_NAME', $user);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm not sure I understand how this would work. My problem comes from the fact that the voter will always either return true or false. I would need it to return an array of objects. Could you please elaborate on the solution?

Comment: Thnak you for your answer, it works :) Just as a comment, I think it also works without the need of injecting the AuthorizationCHeckerInterface, since Symfony already seems to be doing that. So, for me, calling $this->isGranted('VOTER_NAME', $user) works great.

Comment: Yes, I wrote this way because my controllers are POPO invokables and don't extend any class. I prefer to inject everything by myself.